# Underline active link

Tags: javascript

I would like to put an underline on active link
but I can't succeed on selecting the Html.actionLink. This is my **HTML**:

```
<nav class=" navbar-collapse secondaryNav collapse" >

     <div id="highlighter" class="blue"></div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-left:7%" id="menu">
                  <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 border ">@Html.ActionLink("Organize", "Organize", "Home")</li>
                  <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 border " >@Html.ActionLink("Participate", "Participate", "Home")</li>
                  <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 border ">@Html.ActionLink("Support", "Support", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
          </nav>
```

This is the **javascript** i am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#menu li  ').click(function myfunction(){

    // POSITIONNER LA BARRE BLEUE
    $('#highlighter').animate({"left": $(this).offset().left},500);
  })
})
```

I can move the highlighter but only when I click under the list Item but not on the link itself.

Comment: any problem in using CSS?

Comment: not at all but i think if i want keep the active link underlined i  must need javascript somewhere no?

Comment: no, you can use :active pseudo selector, Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:active pseudo selector` for E.g

```
<nav class=" navbar-collapse secondaryNav collapse" >

     <div id="highlighter" class="blue"></div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-left:7%" id="menu">
                  <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 border ">@Html.ActionLink("Organize", "Organize", "Home")</li>
                  <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 border " >@Html.ActionLink("Participate", "Participate", "Home")</li>
                  <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 border ">@Html.ActionLink("Support", "Support", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#highlighter a:active {text-decoration:underline}
```

**1. update after comment**

Add one more event handler to avoid default of `<a>` tag

```
$('#menu li a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: iin my understanding,the problem is with javascript i must select the child of li because if i click on li and not on the link the highlighter moves well